# Component property becomes null after adding formControlName attribute

Tags: angular

I'm trying to setup validation for a component in a reactive form. The component is working fine until I add `formControlName="sellerName"` to the component, now I get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

**Form Component HTML:**
Where the `selectedItem` is the null object

```
<app-dropdown-select formControlName="sellerName" <-- Removing this makes it work
                     [dropdownItems]="sellers">
</app-dropdown-select>
```

**Dropdown Component HTML/template**

```
<div class="button-container">
  <div class="dropdown-button"
       (click)="onClick($event)"
       [class.dropdown-active]="showList && !combinedInput"
       [class.dropdown-input-active]="showList && combinedInput">
    <div class="downdown-selected-item">
      {{selectedItem.name}} {{selectedItem.unit}}
    </div>
    <span class="spacer"></span>
    <i class="material-icons">
      {{buttonIcon}}
    </i>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown-items" *ngIf="showList">
    <div *ngFor="let item of dropdownItems" (click)="onClickItem(item)" class="dropdown-item">
      {{item.name}},
      {{item.description}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown-select',
  templateUrl: './dropdown-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown-select.component.scss'],
  providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => DropdownSelectComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class DropdownSelectComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() combinedInput: boolean;
  @Input() dropdownItems: DropdownItem[];
  @Output() selectedItem: DropdownItem;

  propagateChange = (_: any) => {};
  showList: boolean;
  buttonIcon: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buttonIcon = BUTTON_ICON_INACTIVE;
    this.selectedItem = this.dropdownItems[0];
    console.log(this.dropdownItems);
  }

  onClick() {
    this.toggleShowList();
  }

  toggleShowList() {
    this.showList = !this.showList;
    if (!this.showList) {
      this.buttonIcon = BUTTON_ICON_INACTIVE;
    } else {
      this.buttonIcon = BUTTON_ICON_ACTIVE;
    }
  }

  onClickItem(item) {
    this.showList = false;
    this.selectedItem = item;
        this.propagateChange(this.selectedItem);
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value !== undefined) {
        this.selectedItem = value;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
     console.log('register change');
     this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched() {}

}
```

**Form group:**

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
  description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]],
  cost: [],
  amount: [],   // component
  sellerName: [], // component
  sellerUrl: []
});
```

**Stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rahzjd

Why does this error occur after I add the formControlName attribute and how can I get the value of a list item into the form builder to validate it?

Comment: can you create stackblitz

Comment: @coder, try make that the error say you: add property "name" < app-dropdown-select **name="name"** formControlName="sellerName" [dropdownItems]="sellers" >

Comment: I'll post it on stackblitz

Comment: Using safe-navigation operator `{{selectedItem?.name}} {{selectedItem?.unit}}` should work for you

Comment: @yurzui it works now, how do I get the selectedItem values when they change in myForm

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `ReactiveForms`, by setting the `formControlName` on the field it will allow the value to be set in the control, and you will be able to get your form values via `console.log(this.dataForm.value)` in your `onSubmit()`.

> **Please Note:** Passing an empty array for the formControl `sellerName: [],` results in **ERROR
>   Error: Cannot read property 'name' of null**... you need to pass something, passing `''` in   `sellerName: [''],` resolves the error.

Please see stackblitz below. When you fill out the form and submit, your values are logged in console properly.

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjqjsc?embed=1&file=src/app/form/form.component.html